# What is Object Services class purpose?

Tags: .net, class-design

I'm reading a book on TDD: (btw this question has nothing to to with TDD)

[link to the book on amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Professional-Test-Driven-Development-Applications-ebook/dp/B004X75OGG/ref=la_B004W11KOS_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1406626816&sr=1-1)
Author often mentions/uses Service Classes

For example we would have a Person Object
Person would would have:
  - a "regular" class for deifining the entity **Person**
  - a data access class (lets say we have a db for data persistance) using
    for example a repository patter **PersonRepository**
  - a "service" class (PersonServices) **PersonServices** as author himself explains:

> A PersonService class serves as the business domain class that works with Person objects from a standpoint of enforcing business rules and using Person in business work fl ows.

My question would be is that a way to go with your classes? In the past I would put everything from **Person** class and **PersonServices** into one class.
What type of functionality would go into **Servieces** classes for my objects?

I'm not sure if I understand the quote above (maybe I'm missing the point?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical business rule about `Person` objects is that they must have a unique identifier (e.g. email address, employee code...). Right there you have something that the `Person` class can't enforce on its own: each `Person` only knows its own identifier, but to enforce the rule you need access to *all* existing `Person`s. That is why you need another class with a broader scope than just representing one person, e.g. a Service class (and you can also see how having a Repository class would be useful to write the Service class).

Comment: Would that be the same as People class that inherits list(of Person)?